possible to set default to avoid imagemagick display quality dialog?
Is it possible to set a default (X resource, config file, command line, whatever) for the jpeg quality so that imagemagick's display utility does not always pop up a dialog asking for the value, when saving? Perhaps I should emphasize: I'm asking about display, not convert.
That is, I open a jpeg in display, make some modifications, do the save, and would like to avoid the "enter jpeg quality" popup in the following sequence of dialogs. For my needs, I'm perfectly happy accepting the default (even better would be the quality of the original, if possible). Thanks for any info.

You should ask this on the Imagemagick (GIT) forum. If you do, be sure to mention your IM version and platform.
